# UITableView Implementation

Tags: iphone, uitableview

in the screen shot below, there are UISegmentedControl in between grouped UITableViewCells...it seems.  How does one add other controls in between grouped cells in a UITableView?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables with multiple sections, and sections can have custom header and footer..

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;   // custom view for header. will be adjusted to default or specified header height
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;   // custom view for footer. will be adjusted to default
```

Comment: so, the screenshot has three tables?  one table does not have custom header and footer.  The other two tables have headers?  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the plural there.. It is possible to achieve with 1 table with 3 sections.
section 1&2 with custom footer 
or
just section 2 with custom header & footer.. or.. you get the idea..

Answer (score 4):

You could make the Segmented View the same size as 1 table cell. Dead Simple to do in Interface Builder.